# SP.UI.ModalDialog undefined - Close SharePoint Modal dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, html, sharepoint-hosted-app, sp.ui

I have created a modal dialog in SharePoint with the elements.xml. I use a SharePoint Hosted app. This is my CustomAction Definition:

```
 <CustomAction Id="2c2b7036-4582-4238-8205-b348628c0ed9.OpenMediaDatabase"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="100"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Sequence="10001"
            HostWebDialog="true"
            HostWebDialogHeight="700"
            HostWebDialogWidth="700"
            Title="Medien einfügen"> ...
```

Now I added a "Close"-button to the Dialog:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Abbrechen" onclick="closeDialog()" />
```

And added this code for closing:

```
function closeDialog() {
    var modalDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog;
    modalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, 'Cancelled');
}
```

But I get the error that SP.UI.ModalDialog is not defined.

I added this references to my app:

```
<!-- SharePoint specific references -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Do I have to to something else to get this code working?

EDIT:

I stepped through with the debugger and the method seems to be defined, but I still get this strange error:

[image: Debugging the close method]

EDIT 2:

I forgot this Information: I am using SharePoint Online.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/error-on-sp-js-property-isnullorundefined  resolved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SP.UI lives on another file, that is sp.ui.dialog.js

You need to add it to the script references

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added a reference to the sp.ui.dialog.js but it only changed the error message. Now it says the method "commonModalDialogClose" is undefined. I see the script file in Internet Explorer Debugging Tools so it seems to be available.

Comment: Can you open up the developer console and try this command SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose and see what you get ? this is what you should see http://picpaste.com/Clipboard02.jpg

Comment: I get this: http://picpaste.com/g4ZoqJ66.JPG

Comment: ok, so the function *is* defined... can you show us your full code?

Comment: If I add execute this without parameters in the dev console, the dialog fades out but it does not work from the app

Comment: I added some additional code to my question, but the app is really simple, it does only consists of this few lines.

Comment: try to call the function like this: modalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'Cancelled')

Comment: I get the same error :-( Maybe the Problem is I am using SharePoint Online?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

run this to check if it is a pop-up or iframe

```
    if (window.opener) {
        //alert('inside a pop-up window or target=_blank window');       
    } else if (window.top !== window.self) {
       //inside an iframe}
```

If this is an iframe try this to close the window:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.frameElement.cancelPopUp(); return false;">Close Dialog </a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.frameElement.commitPopup(); return false;">OK </a>');
```

[good article about this](http://wp.ahcheng.com/2013/04/09/calling-dialog-modal-form-in-sharepoint-2013/)