# "Unable to get property 'commonModalDialogClose' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: modal-dialog, office-365-developer

I tried to close a custom .aspx dialog in SharePoint 2013 but I will get this failure message:

> "Unable to get property 'commonModalDialogClose' of undefined or null
>   reference".

Can someone tell me where my problem is, please?

My C# for the .aspx page to close:

```
protected void ButtonOK_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] isDlg = this.Request.QueryString.GetValues("IsDlg");

    if (isDlg != null && (isDlg.Count() == 1 && isDlg[0] == "1"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a [resolution posted by 2GDev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086195/modal-dialog-not-close) on SO that may help you in fixing the issue.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/error-on-sp-js-property-isnullorundefined resolved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Order of JavaScript code execution is the issue.
When your code is executed, `window.SP.UI.ModalDialog` is still undefined. It's because `sp.js` file that *register* `ModalDialog` api is executed **after** (or never, it depends on masterpage).
Some of the solutions are:

1. Register your script later(for example, replace call to `RegisterStartupScript` with `RegisterClientScriptBlock`)  or
2. (preferred one) Wrap your **JavaScript**-code with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){ SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);}, 'sp.js'});`

This is SharePoint "way" to resolve JavaScript dependencies.

Answer (score -4):

Add

```
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: Don't add links to your blog to your post - this is considered [spam](/help/promotion).

Comment: If you're referencing your own blog you should (1) clearly state that this is your own blog and (2) put all relevant content to this answer. If you're blog moves to a new URL, this post would be invalid. Thank you.